# slc: loopback: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

On Ubuntu 15.04, I installed strongloop by "npm install -g strongloop" and installed heimdal-multidev, I got the following:

```
$ slc --version
```

slc (Heimdal 1.6.99)
Copyright 1995-2014 Kungliga Tekniska Högskolan
Send bug-reports to heimdal-bugs@h5l.org

```
$ slc
```

Usage: slc [--version] [--help] command-table

```
$ slc  loopback
```

slc: loopback: No such file or directory

```
$ node -v
```

v5.4.0

```
$ npm -v
```

3.3.12

What's the problem with loopback? thanks a lot!

Comment: Heimdal and strongloop cli soft links are in conflict. In your case slc points to heimdal instead of stronglop cli. Do you need to have heimdal installed?

Comment: I uninstalled heimdal-multidev, but using slc and slc loopback, I got a reminding: sudo apt-get install heimdal-multidev. why? thanks a lot!

Comment: Depending on how you installed node and where npm installs global packages, it is possible that `slc` isn't in sudo's `$PATH`.

Comment: @JesseZhu Now create link to slc command. Try with sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc.js /usr/bin/slc
That should solve your problem if strongloop is installed. I assume that npm packages are on default location.

Comment: @A.Z.It works, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you should post steps that you did to resolve this issue and accept it as answer. It can be helpful for somebody else because it is very common problem.

Comment: @A.Z.Yes, I wanted to do that yesterday, but how? I didn't find "accept .." button or something.